# Jquery opacity on div hover does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, fadeto

I want to show one particular div with the use of fadeTo.
If I hover over div1, then spark1 should be visible and disappear on mouseout..

But it won't do anything when hovering and I don't really know why.

HTML

```
<div class="spark1"></div>

<div class="div1">text</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.spark1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:395px;
    background:url(../img/spark.png) no-repeat;
}
```

JS

```
$('.div1').hover(function(){
    $('.spark1').fadeTo(200, 0);
});
```

**EDIT (update)**

HTML

```
<div class="spark1"></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:#000000;
}

.spark1 {
position:absolute;
width:27px;
height:27px;
top:70px;
left:395px;
background-color:#ff0000;
filter:alpha(opacity=0); opacity:0.0;
}
```

JS

```
            $('.project1').hover(function(){
                $('.spark1').fadeTo(200, 1);
            },
            function(){
                $('.spark1').fadeTo(200, 0);
            });
```

It still won't trigger, I don't get it..

Comment: That is an incomplete hover function. Please refer to the jQuery docs for an example.

Comment: It's complete, but probably not what was intended.

Comment: @Diodeus. There is a `.hover( handlerInOut(eventObject) )` overload.

Comment: @DidierGhys but it doesn't achieve the intended purpose of "appear and disappear"

Comment: 5 complete answers within an hour... nice going stackoverflow :P

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone. I now know what the correct code is, but the hover wouldn't trigger at all and with your codes still won't.. So something else must be messing with it. I'll update the code to what I have now

Answer (score 1):

you should `stop the animation` if the event trigger before completion of previous. try this

```
$('.div1').hover(function(){
    $('.spark').stop(true,true).fadeTo(200, 1);
},function(){
    $('.spark').stop(true,true).fadeTo(200, 0);
});
```

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/mK4m6/11/

Comment: you made it reverse. When we hover over it should be visible :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you use the correct css classes names

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/mK4m6/)

You define a css class `.spark {  }` but in you code you use the class name `.spark1`.
Choose one or the other.

Comment: you made it reverse. When we hover over it should be visible :P

Comment: Yeah, it was correct in my code, this was just an example but good eye

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your hover function. It has 2 call back methods:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".div1").hover(
      function(event) {
          //hover in
          $(".spark1").fadeTo(200,1);
      },
      function(event) {
          $(".spark1").fadeTo(200,0);
      });
});​
```

Below is a working script:

http://jsfiddle.net/U8rzJ/7/

Comment: While I suspect that this case calls for both arguments, .hover() *can* have 1 argument.  It's in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2

Comment: @SurrealDreams yeh, this case calls for both arguments. But yes I agree with you too

Answer (score 0):

Building on Didier's good catch of the class names, there's a problem with your hover() script.  hover() can take one or two functions as arguments - if you supply just one, it's executed on both mouseover and mouseout.  You'll want this, I think:

```
$('.div1').hover(function(){
    //fade in to 100%
    $('.spark').fadeTo(200, 100);
},
function(){

    $('.spark').fadeTo(200, 0);
});
```

This fades the .spark in on mousein and fades it back out on mouseout.  If you want to animate on mouseout only, I'd switch from .hover() to .mouseout().

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="spark1"></div>

<div class="div1">text</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
width:300px;
height:300px;
}

.spark1 {
position:absolute;
width:27px;
height:27px;
top:70px;
left:395px;
background-color:#ff0000;
filter:alpha(opacity=0); opacity:.0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.div1').hover(function(){
    $('.spark1').fadeTo(200, 1);
},
function(){
    $('.spark1').fadeTo(200, 0);
});
```

Then it all works out.
1. Use correct class names
2. Set the initial opacity of spark1 to 0
3. On mouseenter fade the opacity to 1
4. On mouseleave fade the opacity to 0